# Ruby: How to use hash as argument of a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to define a helper in Rails:

```
# Usage:
# selector_link('This is New', tab: 'new')
# selector_link('This is like sorter', sort: 'like_count')
# selector_link('This is number 7', number: 7)
def selector_link2(link_text, param_name: param_content)
  link_to link_text, url_for(param_name: param_content), class: ('active'if params[:param_name] == param_content)
  # Should Generate:
  # link_to link_text, url_for(tab: 'new'), class: ('active'if params[:tab] == 'new')
  # link_to link_text, url_for(sort: 'like_count'), class: ('active'if params[:sort] == 'like_count')
  # link_to link_text, url_for(number: 7), class: ('active'if params[:number] == 7)
end
```

The problem is that, I don't know how to make the `key` in `url_for(key: path)` to accept the input `hash's key`, and `params[:key]` also seems a invalid syntax.

What is the correct way of wrting this method?

UPDATE:
This is what I end up with

```
def selector_link2(link_text, link = {})
  key = link.first[0]
  value = link.first[1]
  link_to link_text, url_for(link), class: ('active'if params[link[key].to_s] == link[value])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called named parameter or [keyword argument](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments), so that

```
def x(a, b: 'test')
  puts "a = #{a}"
  puts "b = #{b}"
end
```

could be called as:

```
x 123, b: 'yay'
# a = 123
# b = yay
```

You could also type it like this:

```
def x(a, b: nil) 
  b ||= anything      
end
```

**EDIT 1**: So in your case (if I'm not misunderstood), it should be something like this:

```
def selector_link(link_text, tab: path)
  link_to link_text, url_for(key: tab), class: ('active' if tab == 'new')
end
```

**EDIT 2:** Or something like this:

```
def selector_link(link_text, opt={})
  link_to link_text, url_for(opt), class: ('active' if opt[:tab] == 'new')
end
```

Both function can be called as `selector_link('a',tab:'new')`

**EDIT 3** for your last question edit, it should be something like this:

```
def selector_link(link_text, opt={})
  active = nil
  active = 'active' if !opt[:tab].nil? and opt[:tab] == 'new'
  active = 'active' if !opt[:sort].nil? and opt[:sort] == 'like_count' 
  link_to link_text, url_for(opt), class: active
end
```

**EDIT 4** If Rail's helper can access `params`, you could type it like this:

```
def selector_link(link_text, opt={})
  key = opt.first[0] # get the first :key or :param_name
  link_to link_text, url_for(opt), class: ('active' if opt[key].to_s == params[key].to_s)
end 

# call it using:
selector_link('This is New', tab: 'new')
selector_link('This is like sorter', sort: 'like_count')
selector_link('This is number 7', number: 7)
```

If `params` not accessible from helper, you must pass it manually:

```
def selector_link(link_text, params, opt={})
  key = opt.first[0]
  link_to link_text, url_for(opt), class: ('active' if opt[key].to_s == params[key].to_s)
end 

# call it using:
selector_link('This is New', params, tab: 'new')
selector_link('This is like sorter', params, sort: 'like_count')
selector_link('This is number 7', params, number: 7)
```

**EDIT 5** last update, for the repetitive part

```
def selector_link2(link_text, link = {})
  key, value = link.first
  link_to link_text, url_for(link), class: ('active' if params[key].to_s == value.to_s)
end
```

Comment: I may not be clear initially, I want to reuse the name of `b` and its value. How can I do that?

Comment: see `EDIT 2` maybe that's what you're looking for

Comment: I need to change the `:tab` in `params[:tab]` into argument, how can I do that? I update my code with 2 example, maybe that's more clear.

Comment: see `EDIT 4` maybe that what you need?

Comment: Could you explain why using params as an argument?, I think usage should be `selector_link('This is New', tab: 'new')`, `selector_link('This is like sorter', sort: 'like_count')`. There is no need for `params`

Comment: The first alternative should only used when `params` can be accessed within the helper, the second one when `params` cannot be accessed within helper..

Comment: It finally works, could you see my UPDATE? I still feel it's kind repetative.

Comment: see `EDIT 5` `link[key]` is always equal to `value`